# Community Promotion Ads - 2017

Tags: discussion, community-ads

It is a bit late into this new year, being that we're already in the second month, but we are now cycling the Community Promotion Ads for 2017!

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- code puzzle blogs and websites
- interesting challenge sites
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be 300 x 250 pixels, or double that if high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB
- If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/11408).

Comment: [Link to previous year](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/9463/8478) for reference.

Comment: I suspect that the text of the question has been copy-pasted for several years now, and in the meantime the adoption of https worldwide has increased. Is there any reason not to state that the image URL should use either a protocol-less `//` or `https://`?

Comment: May I suggest that, if high DPI, file size limit should be 600 KB instead?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Now there is no need to state it anymore, SE will choke on non-HTTPS.

Comment: hm, it's already 2018...:p

Answer (score 82):

[image: Over 400 online interpreters. Free of charge, open source, and ad-free.]

Comment: [Repost from 2016.](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9536/12012)

Comment: I really do like that it is free, ad-free also

Comment: How about making tio a offline app? js-linux can help https://vfsync.org/vm.html

Comment: @ЕвгенийНовиков I'm not really sure what I'm looking at or if it would add anything over the Docker image that already exists. If you'd like to discuss this, please join me in http://talk.tryitonline.net.

Comment: The [ad tool-tip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnfO7.png) talks about only "over 200 online interpreters" on my screen (I guess still technically correct)

Comment: @LarsW Apparently, I managed to overlook that during the past two updated to the image... Fixed, thank you.

Answer (score 66):

[image: Have a challenge idea? Iron out its bugs. Join us in the Sandbox!]

Comment: [Repost from 2016](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9466/194)

Answer (score 29):

[image: Esoteric IDE — Interpreter/Debugger for esoteric programming languages]

Comment: Repost of [Timwi's ad from 2016.](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9554/8478)

Answer (score 24):

[image: Bounties for everybody]

Comment: Image doesn't load for for reason for me

Comment: Hmmm.... it seems to come and go. I'm guessing the server is being overloaded. When it fails I can see it returning 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: @JamesHolderness yeah, I think so. It should calm down after the rush to post ads is over though.

Comment: Doesn't this ad violate the rule that images must be hosted on imgur? Or does this ad have an exception?

Comment: @mbomb007 it's been used in the past on almost every site, I'm fairly certain it's okay. I'll make a meta.se post later though.

Comment: Returns a 500 Server Error.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer [meta-tag:status-norepro]

Comment: @Riker It was really returning a 500 error, but it seems to have been fixed... for now.

Comment: OK returning 500 error again... not sure what's doing that.

Comment: @mbomb007 But I thought that old http images were still working.

Comment: I think we should just get rid of the bounty ad if we can't rely on it.

Comment: @mbomb007 it's up for me....

Comment: @programmer5000 uh, there's definitely not 0 bounties active. There's 5 atm, worth 450 total. (1 is new as of 30 minutes ago)

Comment: It's broken again...

Comment: @Dennis no repro

Comment: Image isn't loading again.

Comment: @MDXF no-repro.

Comment: If this is broken, just clear your cache and wait, please only comment if this is broken for 12+ hours.

Answer (score 23):

[image: Bookmarklet — no install needed!]

Answer (score 11):

[image: Help wanted to build PPCG v2]

Comment: The wrench icon used is licensed under CC-BY-SA and created by Dave Gandy.

Answer (score 8):

[image: Code a mobile app for PPCG!]

Comment: [Credit to Adám](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40237956#40237956)

Answer (score 1):

[image: Help this community grow -- follow us on twitter!]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting

Answer (score -3):

[image: The Esolang wiki sports over 1200 esoteric programming languages]

Comment: Not sure about the wording. Suggestions are welcome. 
Also not sure if a border is required for this.

Mouseover text: _The Esolangs wiki sports over 1200 esoteric programming languages_

Comment: I think the fonts used are a little jarring.  Especially the Esolangs.org part and all the languages in the back ground.

Comment: It's worth bearing in mind that when it displays in the sidebar, most users will see this ad significantly smaller than this, rendering the background illegible.

Comment: I like how @user2428118 is actually user 13486

Answer (score -6):

[image: Join over 20 students in their efforts to learn Jelly. Just request access and start working!]

Comment: While I appreciate having an ad for JHT, the design of this particular ad is kinda... gross in my opinion.

Comment: @Pavel well, it's not worth the effort for a better version since it's 2018 already and there should be a new community ads post, but the Unicode is supposed to show the trouble :p