# Community Promotion Ads - 2018

Tags: discussion, community-ads

It's almost February in 2018, which isn't supposed to be the proper time to cycle these, but for this year it'll be once again, so we'll be refreshing the **Community Promotion Ads** for this year now!

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- code puzzle blogs and websites
- interesting challenge sites
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be 300 x 250 pixels, or double that if high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB
- If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/14687).

Comment: When will the ads actually be live? It seems that I'm still getting 2017 ads...

Comment: **Update**: this year's ads are now live!

Answer (score 63):

[image: Over 600 online interpreters. Free of charge, open source, and ad-free.]

Comment: [Repost from 2017.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11413/12012)

Answer (score 40):

[image: Have a challenge idea? Iron out its bugs. Join us in the Sandbox!]

Comment: [Repost from 2017](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11411/45941)

Answer (score 32):

[image: Bookmarklet — no install needed!]

Comment: TIL about this very useful tool, thanks!

Answer (score 27):

[image: Esolangs.org - the esoteric programming languages wiki]

Answer (score 22):

[image: Know how to vote!]

Comment: [Repost](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10138/63187)

Comment: As a minor improvement I would suggest potentially moving the second line a tad to the right such that _g_'s decender does not touch _i_'s dot.

Comment: I think _byte count_ (without the hyphen) is more widely used than _byte-count_.

Comment: This ad makes my mind automatically insert "Pick two."

Answer (score 13):

[image: Bounties for everybody]

Comment: [Repost from 2017](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11415/45941)

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder See the comments on the post from last year.

Comment: PSA: If this is broken/incorrect, clear your cache and wait. If it doesn't come back up in 24 hours, then you can leave a comment.

Comment: I no longer think this is worth having. Just look at the "featured" tab.

Answer (score 9):

[image: Want to improve your Jelly skills? – Join Jelly HyperTraining!]

Comment: I honestly don't like the border too much, but I don't have much time to fix it now. If anyone can do it for me, you can get a non-border version [here](https://imgur.com/a/ULuiX).

Comment: Good idea. You inspired me to make [such an ad](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14708/43319) myself.

Comment: just a minor quibble, the fact that the J does not align with the "H T" really bothers me

Comment: Note that the image of this ad has been updated since it was posted, you can visit the revision history to view it. The new image has been created by [Adám](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/43319/adám). Feedback is welcome!

Comment: `Want to post competitive answers` is there *any* Jelly answer that isn't competitive?

Comment: @MDXF yes there are.

Comment: The image for this add appears to have disappeared.

Answer (score 9):

[image: J and K are on topic too!]

Comment: Do you pronounce "APL" as "apple" ever?

Comment: @mbomb007 It's pronounced as the letters individually, but the room name is hardly the first Apple-based pun APL has. For example, Dyalog saves your session in a file called `aplcore`.

Comment: @mbomb007 No, never when by itself, however I do when compound: [APLTree](https://aplwiki.com/CategoryAplTree), [Py'n'APL](https://github.com/Dyalog/pynapl), and as Pavel said, "aplcore" memory dumps. Apple APL puns [date way back](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_(programming_language)#/media/File:I_like_APL_graphic.jpg) and are [still comon](http://www.dyalog.com/50-years-of-apl.htm).

Comment: PynAPL, funny. It also could've been APL-Py.

Comment: @mbomb007 [Taken](https://aplpy.github.io/).

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you design this ad yourself? It's very well done.

Comment: Also, what does `⍺*⎕` do?

Comment: @Pavel Thanks. Yes, I made it myself. In a dfn (anonymous lamda) it means the left argument, `⍺`, (leftmost letter of Greek alphabet) to the power of, `*`, evaluated input, `⎕` (ideogram for a console). [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1Hf1EdtE4yrH/Xu0gKya03@/zcCAA "APL (Dyalog Unicode) – Try It Online") `⍺*⎕` is what you get if you hold the APL shifting key and type `apl`: Go to [TryAPL](http://tryapl.org/) and type Backtick,`a`,Backtick,`p`,Backtick,`l`!

Answer (score -4):

[image: Code a mobile app for PPCG!]

Comment: [Repost from 2017](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13987/30525)

Comment: [Credit to Adám](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40237956#40237956)

Answer (score -7):

[image: Help this community grow -- follow us on twitter!]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting

Comment: [FTFY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBre4.png).

Comment: @flawr [FTFY](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/14688/revisions).

Comment: @Adám Though the Twitter account also only has one _P_ in its logo.

Comment: @JonathanFrech You're right. Rolled back.