# How does following PPCG on Twitter help the community grow?

Tags: discussion, site-health, stackexchange, advertising

[Grace Note](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2414/grace-note) posted [a community ad](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14688/43319) which seems to claim that following PPCG on Twitter will help the community grow:

[image: Help this community grow -- follow us on twitter!]

How does that work?

Comment: I'd assume it's because more people would stumble across Twitter account and join PPCG. Not that it's working, considering the Twitter account isn't paid attention to but...

Comment: Is `Twiller` some joke I am not getting or did you intend to write `Twitter`?

Comment: @JonathanFrech You can tell that I don't [instagoogletweetface](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PDet9v1CT24&feature=youtu.be&t=34s), can't you?

Answer (score 2):

A bot tweets links to questions using similar criteria to the Hot Network Questions sidebar. HNQ is one of the biggest drivers of traffic to the smaller Stack Exchange sites, but the intention is clearly that the Twitter account should also drive traffic. Based on how Twitter works, the idea is probably that community members retweet links to questions they like.

I personally consider that HNQ is actively harmful, because it promotes trivial questions rather than good ones and gives people a distorted view of the site. On that basis I have downvoted the Twitter community ad, and I suspect that a good proportion of the other downvotes are based on similar reasoning.

Comment: "I personally consider that HNQ is actively harmful, because it promotes trivial questions rather than good ones and gives people a distorted view of the site." - I partially agree, but I think the HNQ all in all has a positive effect on the site, bringing new users, some of whom stick around and eventually learn about the site in greater depth and become valuable contributors for the community.

Comment: @Steadybox I tend to disagree, that the HNQ helps us more than harms us. You'd be surprised how bad the HNQ reinforces FGITW and trivial questions and answers. While I do agree there are tangible benefits through the HNQ, I would rather see its downsides removed from the site at the cost of its upsides.

Comment: I can't guess whether the costs or benefits of the HNQ are more significant. Despite originally finding PPCG through HNQ, I'd be very much in favour of switching it off for a trial period (maybe 3 or 6 months) so we can estimate what differences that makes (good and bad).